# ifstream error with g++ but compiles with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, g++

I have been using Visual Studio for a project I am working on, though it must also compile with GCC on Linux. I have completed my project and it runs fine, but I sent the files over to my Linux shell and I receiving an error with a trivial line of code:

```
std::ifstream input(s);
```

This gives me error saying there is no matching function. `s` is an `std::string` by the way.
Can anyone enlighten me why this runs under Visual Studio but not GCC, even though I am looking at the documentation for ifstream? Perhaps an old version of GCC?

**EDIT**: GCC version is 4.2.1  The exact error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char,  
std::char_traits<char>>::basic_ifstream(std::string&)'
```

**EDIT 2:** Relevant code:

```
std::string s = "";
if(argc == 2)
    s = argv[1];
else{
    std::cout << "Bad filename?" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
std::ifstream input(s);
```

Comment: this: http://ideone.com/w6IJ5 works fine; you should probably post your complete code.

Comment: @RoryYorke Updated with what I believe is the only relevant code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download latest version of GCC, and compile your program with `-std=c++0x` option. In C++11, stream classes has constructor which takes `std::string` as argument, and GCC by default doesn't enable C++11, so you need to enable by providing `-std=c++0x` compiler option.

If you cannot use C++11, then do this:

```
std::ifstream input(s.c_str());
```

This should compile, both in C++03 and C++11.

Comment: I attempted to change the code by calling `open` but it also gets an error.

Comment: @AustinHenley: See my updated answer. Also, when you see error, POST IT. Please don't make us guess about the error.